# Higher order variations of Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Let $(W_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a standard Brownian motion. Denote $\mathcal{P}:=\{0=t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_n=T\}$ and $\|\mathcal{P}\|:=\max_j|t_j - t_{j-1}|$. I would like to show that 
$$
V^3(W_t):=\lim_{\|\mathcal{P}\|\to0}\sum_{j=1}^n(W_{t_j} - W_{t_{j-1}})^3\to0\quad{\text{in}}\quad L^2.
$$
I am able to prove this for convergence in probability (see https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17827, for example), but am struggling with the $L^2$ case.

**EDIT**: I've been a bit silly - it just occurred to me that the link I posted implicitly proves the $L^2$ convergence of the limit:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[\left(\sum_{j=1}^n (W_{t_j}-W_{t_{j-1}})^3\right)^2\right]
&=
 \sum_{i,j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[(W_{t_i}-W_{t_{i-1}})^3(W_{t_j}-W_{t_{j-1}})^3\right]\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[(W_{t_j}-W_{t_{j-1}})^6\right]\\
&=15\sum_{j=1}^n (t_j-t_{j-1})^3\\
&\leq 15T\|\mathcal{P}\|^2\to0\quad\text{as}\quad\|\mathcal{P}\|\to0.
\end{align*}

However, I would also be interested to know if there is a simple proof for $V^p(W_t)$ with $p>2$, and whether the result also holds with probability one. Any hints or references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that $|\sum_{i=1}^n(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})^3|\leq \sup|W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i}|\sum_{i=1}^n(W_{t_{i+1}}-W_{t_i})^2 \rightarrow 0$ since we have standart properties of the quadratic variation.

If I remember correctly the convergence is in $L^2$ but feel free to correct me

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I can see how this observation could be used to prove $L^1$ convergence, but why it's useful in the $L^2$ case isn't completely clear to me I'm afraid.

Comment: There is a standart result that the quadratic variation of a Brownian Motion on $[0,t]$ converges to $t$ in $L^2$ when the mesh goes to $0$. Note also that the supremum above will tend to $0$ as we refine the partition